# Is there a way for the textfield to only accept Alphabets and white spaces in swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to validate if in my first name field there exists a special character or number inputted by the user.

I've tried this code but when my name has a space like for example Mark John it is considered an error.

```
let characterset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
           if name.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset.inverted) != nil {
            return false
        }else{
            return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a space character to the string you use to initialize your CharacterSet.

Or you can use:

```
let characterSet = CharacterSet.letters.union(.whitespaces)
```

This allows letters from any alphabet.

Unrelated but you can replace that `if/else` with:

```
return name.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterset) != nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression like.

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*[^A-Za-z ].*", options: [])
    if regex.firstMatch(in: nameValue, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nameValue.characters.count)) != nil {
     self.showAlert(message: "Must not contain Number in Name")

    } else {

           }
}
catch {

}
```